# Using more than one <f:viewParam .. /> in <f:metadata .. causes error

Tags: jsf

I want to parse two parameters from the URL but when I include two f:viewParam in header of page i get an error:
The metadata component needs to be nested within a f:metadata tag. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within f:metadata

An example of a URL:
http://domain.com?email=blah@dom.com&key=4793e258-518f-432d-9af2-8d639a13757d

I'm using JSF 2.2.6 and I tried swapping the name space (below) from xmlns.jcp.org to java.sun.com  but that made no difference.

My simplified page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="email" value="#{credentialsBacking.returnedEmail}"/>
            <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{credentialsBacking.returnedActivationKey}"/>
        </f:metadata>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for putting the `f:metadata` tag inside the `h:head`? BTW, use the `xmlns` namespace, it's the right one for JSF 2.2.

Comment: I thought that was the best place for it? I have tried inputting it in the body though, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with no problem in Mojarra 2.2.6 and Tomcat 7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="email" />
            <f:viewParam name="key" />
        </f:metadata>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    #{email} - #{key}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Also this one does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="email" value="#{bean1.email}" />
            <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{bean1.key}" />
        </f:metadata>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    #{bean1.email} - #{bean1.key}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1 {

    public Bean1() {
        System.out.println("Bean created");
    }

    private String email;

    private String key;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        System.out.println(email);
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
        System.out.println(key);
    }

}
```

It doesn't matter where I place the `<f:metadata />` inside the `<html />`, parameters are properly set.

Having seen your last comments, the issue seems to be related with **your development tool not properly deploying resources to the server**. Clean up your workspace and check the proper content is being copied.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why, but I recreated the project from scratch and the issue went away. Curiously I had to use the name space of  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" instead of xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" to get the parameters to save to the bean.